Making horizontal lines (rules) meet at a specific y-position
I am working on an exam paper. It requests that students write multiple things (Name, grade, school, city, as shown), and horizontal lines are given for details to be written above them.
I want to match the lines so they meet at a common y-axis point, such that all the lines end at the exact same place on the paper's width. Here is the code for the fbox:
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\LARGE{Name: \noindent\rule{8cm}{0.1pt}\par
\vspace{0.1cm}
Grade: \noindent\rule{8cm}{0.1pt}\par
\vspace{0.1cm}
School: \noindent\rule{8cm}{0.1pt}\par
\vspace{0.1cm}
City: \noindent\rule{8cm}{0.1pt}\par
\vspace{0.1cm}
}
\end{minipage}}

I'd appreciate it if I could get help on this. Thanks

Welcome. // Please add the missing lines to make your code compile. // Will you print it and fill out manually? Or do you need an electronic option?

With the package tabularray.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[r] X},
    column{1} = {font=\LARGE},
    %column{2} = {cmd={\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\rule{8cm}{0.1pt}}}},
    column{2} = {cmd={\rule{8cm}{0.1pt}}},
    hline{1,Z} = {1pt,solid},
    vline{1,Z} = {1pt,solid},
    rowsep = 0.1cm,
    }
Name:&\\
Grade:&\\
School:&\\
City:&\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



You can use \leaders TeX primitive:
\def\myrulefill{\leaders\hrule height.1pt\hfill\kern.5em\null}

\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\vskip0.1cm
\LARGE \parindent=.5em
Name: \myrulefill
\vskip0.1cm
Grade: \myrulefill
\vskip0.1cm
School: \myrulefill
\vskip0.1cm
City: \myrulefill
\vskip0.1cm
\end{minipage}}


Also \vskip0.1cm should be changed to a parskip setting.

Or \baselineskip setting.
